# Implementation of resizable array (Vector or ArrayList) in C

Tags: c, vectors

I've implemented a very simple resizable integer array in C, only including functionality to add and remove elements at various indexes.

I haven't looked at using void pointers to handle any type of data yet. I'm mainly wondering if my structure of the code is okay, with the header file containing external API details and the source file hiding away implementation detail.

`vector.h`

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

typedef struct vector_struct* Vector;

extern Vector vector_create();
extern void vector_destroy(Vector vector);
extern void vector_add(Vector vector, int* element);
extern void vector_add_index(Vector vector, int* element, int index);
extern void vector_remove(Vector vector, int index);
extern void vector_pop(Vector vector);
extern void vector_print(Vector vector);

#endif
```

`vector.c` file:

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct vector_struct {
  int capacity;
  int number_of_elements;
  int* elements;
};

/*
Private function to allocate memory for vector creation
*/
static void* get_memory(size_t size) {
  void* memory;
  if ((memory = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return memory;
}

/*
Private function to resize the amount of memory allocated for the given vector
*/
static void resize_vector(Vector vector, size_t size) {
  if ((vector->elements = realloc(vector->elements, size)) == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  vector->capacity = size / sizeof(int);
}

/*
Create and initialize a vector for use
*/
extern Vector vector_create() {
  Vector vector = get_memory(sizeof(Vector));

  vector->capacity = 10;
  vector->number_of_elements = 0;
  vector->elements = get_memory(sizeof(int) * 10);

  return vector;
}

/*
Free memory allocated for vector
*/
extern void vector_destroy(Vector vector) {
  free(vector->elements);
  free(vector);
}

/*
Add given element to the end of the vector
*/
extern void vector_add(Vector vector, int* element) {
  if (vector->number_of_elements+1 > vector->capacity) {
    resize_vector(vector, (vector->capacity * 2) * sizeof(int));
  }

  vector->elements[vector->number_of_elements] = *element;
  vector->number_of_elements++;
}

/*
Add given element at the given index in the vector
*/
extern void vector_add_index(Vector vector, int* element, int index) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= vector->number_of_elements) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (vector->number_of_elements+1 > vector->capacity) {
    resize_vector(vector, (vector->capacity * 2) * sizeof(int));
  }

  for(int i=vector->number_of_elements; i>index; i--) {
    vector->elements[i] = vector->elements[i-1];
  }

  vector->elements[index] = *element;
  vector->number_of_elements++;
}

/*
Removes element at given index, shifting all elements after that index
to the left once in order to fill in the empty index 
*/
extern void vector_remove(Vector vector, int index) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= vector->number_of_elements) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for(int i=index; i<vector->number_of_elements-1; i++) {
    vector->elements[i] = vector->elements[i+1];
  }
  vector->number_of_elements--;

  if (vector->number_of_elements < (vector->capacity / 2)) {
    resize_vector(vector, (vector->capacity / 2) * sizeof(int));
  }
}

/*
Removes the last element in the vector
*/
extern void vector_pop(Vector vector) {
  if (vector->number_of_elements < 1) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  vector->number_of_elements--;
}

/*
Prints the vector's contents
*/
extern void vector_print(Vector vector) {
  printf("Capacity of vector: %d\nContents:\n", vector->capacity);
  printf("[");
  for (int i=0; i<vector->number_of_elements; i++) {
    printf((i == vector->number_of_elements-1) ? " %d " : " %d,", vector->elements[i]);
  }
  printf("]\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Do not `typedef` a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932/is-typedefing-a-pointer-type-considered-bad-practice).
- `exit` on a bad index is a bit too harsh. Consider returning a success/failure indication instead.
- `vector->capacity *= 2` and `vector->capacity /= 2` embody the reallocation policy. It doesn't feel right that this policy is spread across many functions. I recommend to consolidate it in a single function (`resize_vector` is a good candidate), and call it unconditionally with the *desired* new size.
- `number_of_elements` is not exposed to the client. It means that the client cannot iterate over the vector elements, which severely limits the utility of the array. Either expose it, or provide a mapping interface, along the lines of

  ```
  typedef (*op)(int, void *);
  .... map(Vector vector, op, int, void *);
  ```

  (the `void *` argument to share a state across the `op` invocations).

Comment: First point is refuted by the dupe of the post you linked to, at least for this case.